# Dont know how to add bold to a label in winforms powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, fonts, label

i tried several things from different post, but i just cant seem to make it bold

Does anybody knows how to accomplish this?

```
$LabelComputer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelComputer.Text = "Computer Settings"
$LabelComputer.AutoSize = $True
$LabelComputer.Top="5" 
$LabelComputer.Left="10" 
$LabelComputer.Anchor="Left,Top" 
$form1.Controls.Add($LabelComputer)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're going to need to create a `Font` object and give that to the `Font` property on your label control.

Unfortunately with these objects you need to give it a few things in the constructor, so you can't just create a blank object and fill it with details like you can with the label.

To that end you can do this before adding the control to your form:

```
$LabelComputer.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
```

You'll notice in inside that `new(...)` three things:

1. The name of a font
2. The size of the text (you can omit this, but it will default to 1)
3. The font style, in this case bold.

You'll need to adjust the Font and Size to fit your needs.

Note, if you're creating many labels using the same font, create your font object and assign it to `$LabelFont` then your property on the label can be `$LabelComputer.Font = $LabelFont`.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can I set the font size and font bold object separate in Powershell?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to above @ToTi, the following worked for me (verified using vs 5.1)

```
$LabelComputer.Font = new-object System.Drawing.Font('Ariel',8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
```

Comment: you didn't add anything to his answer; the only change you made is seemingly misspelling "Arial"

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about powershell version discrepancy, but for sure solution with `[System.Drawing.Font]::new` is not working in powershell 2.0 (Idk how its in 5.1 version).

I found another solution how you can set text in label to bold. Like this:

```
$LabelComputer.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
```

Where instead of Bold you can use following: Regular, Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikeout

Answer (score 1):

I was strugging with this today, managed to come up with this whereby it keeps the original font type and size and just amends it to a Bold style.

```
$mylabel.Font = [system.drawing.font]'$mylabel.Font.Name$mylabel.Font.Size, style=Bold'
```

Works on Version 5.1 of PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you use what language, but if want to set bold for Lable then you can use Font.

```
$LabelComputer = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: its an powershell script, this didnt work, maybe some other ideas?, do i need to upload the full script?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know powershell. I can not help you. But Other people will help you. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
$LabelComputer.Font.Bold = $true
```

Comment: tried that but im getting the response back "Bold" is a ReadOnly property